# Can I contribute my existing Treasury Bills into a Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira, contribution, government-bonds

Let's say I have paper 30yr treasury bills sitting in a safe that don't mature for 9 years.  Can I place those bills into a Roth IRA?  If so, are they valued against my contribution limit at face value? When they mature (in 2022) will I still owe taxes on the past 21 years of interest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  New Deposits to a Traditional or Roth IRA must be cash. Conversions are a different story, so the Traditional IRA contents need not be sold to convert to Roth.

See [IRS publication 590 chapter 1 – Traditional IRAs](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/ch01.html#en_US_2012_publink1000230371):

> - Contributions, except for rollover contributions, must be in cash. [...]

... and [IRS publication 590 chapter 2 – Roth IRAs](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/ch02.html#en_US_2012_publink1000230969):

> A Roth IRA is an individual retirement plan that, except as explained in this chapter, is subject to the rules that apply to a traditional IRA [...]

Comment: Thanks!  Here's an additional secondary source: http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/stocksforira.asp